# I get "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation" for the simplist recursion

Tags: warning-messages, recursion

I typed `f[n_] := n f[n - 1]` that I found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForFunctions.html) in the official reference and still get the error when I try `f[10]` like the official reference, here is the error

```
In[2]:= f[n_] := n f[n - 1]

In[3]:= f[10]

During evaluation of In[3]:= $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of f[-1012-1]. >>

Out[3]= Hold[10 f[10 - 1]]
```

I thought this might me because of older definitions, so I tried `Quit[]` and started again but it's still the same, actually this block of code was after the Quit[]

Comment: You don't have a termination condition, like the necessary: `f[1]=1`

Comment: I thought of that but I didn't know where to put the termination condition, I didn't know that they meant that in the reference, thank you very much for this

Comment: Also, see [`Functions That Remember Values They Have Found`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you haven't defined a start/seed for your recursion. In the current form the evaluation will not terminate anywhere. Providing an additional line of

```
f[1]=1
```

will settle the recursion problem and yield a proper implementation of the factorial.